# VSCode 'The file is in the program because: Default library for target 'es3''

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode. After the last update of the IDE, I see this error (Even if I didn't open any project to work on).

[image]

I googled it, and I tried several actions according to this link:
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43838 
but none of them seems to work.

Anyone faced the issue? (I'm not using TypeScript in any of my projects and I don't have any tsconfig.ts file). Is it related to one of my VSCode extensions?

Comment: Same issue here..

Comment: The issue solved for me on the latest VS code update.

Comment: It looks like it occurred in version `1.74.0` and it was promptly fixed in version `1.74.1` and documented [in this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/168420). **So all you have to do is just update your VS Code installation.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a general update problem about visual-studio-code with the last update. Issue can  be followed from here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/168420

Installing [JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-next) extension is helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

Configure .eslintrc.json in your folder again and reload the vs code
example:
[.eslintrc.json file for salesforce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRZln.png)
Or
you can refer below link to config your eslint file
https://eslint.org/docs/latest/user-guide/configuring/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).